# Getting error in connecting Facebook in ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I have implemented Facebook wall post using Facebook Graph and FBConnect files for ios 4.It was working fine in ios 4 and ios 5 devices ,but now does not effect anything.

But when i tried to connect Facebook in ios 6 device, it gives me an error as shown in following image.
[image]

I have searched for this but could not get solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Facebbok integration in iOS6 is very easy,Apple include facebook feature in iOS6,so use apple API for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

you have use Apple APIs for iOS6, read the following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Use may use the following code for iOS6

> ```
> if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
>             if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {  
>                 SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
>                 SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
>                     if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
>                         NSLog(@"Cancelled");
>                     } else
>                     {
>                         NSLog(@"Done");
>                         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Successfully Posted On Facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
>                         [alert show];
>                         [alert release];
>                     }
>                     [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
>                 };
>                 controller.completionHandler =myBlock;
>                 [controller setInitialText:@"Test Message"];
>                 //   [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com"]];
>                 //   [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fb.png"]];
>                 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
>             }
>             else{
>                 NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
>                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Accounts" message:@"There are no Facebook accounts configured.You can add or create a Facebook account in Settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
>                 [alert show];
>                 [alert release];
>             }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

open app in facebook "http://developers.facebook.com/"

apps>>your app >> setting >>Edit settings>> Advanced>>Migrations>>Disable all Breaking Changed

Try this one it will work.